# How to pass parameter from one render to another to load specific content in template

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working in a ruby on rails project but since I'm a frontend developer I've got no knowledge on the ruby on rails way of doing things.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to pass a parameter to another file which I can then use to load the specific content, but I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible.

`file 1`:

```
<%= render "partials/lightbox/lightbox", card: 'new-card' %>
```

Then I want this parameter to be used in `file 2` :

```
<div class="site-overlay">
  <div class="lightbox lightbox--medium light-theme">
    <%= render "partials/lightbox/content/{myparameter}" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which will render the lightbox with the content I passed from `file 1`.

How can I pass a variable to the `render` in `file 2` from `file 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy

```
<%= render partial: 'path/to/partial/file2', locals: {var2: var1} %>
```

Above code will pass var1 from partial file1 to partial file2 and it will be accessible in file2 partial as **var2**

Remember partials are named as _filename but when using render you write without underscore.

I hope this helps

Comment: And how exactly would I pass it to the render in file 2? #{myVar}?

Comment: Above code already has passed the variable to partial file2, once in file2 you can output the variable like <%= var2 %> and if you want to do string concatenation <%= "Hello  I am #{var2}" %>

Answer (score 4):

In rails locals is used for passing vaiable

```
<%= render "partial_name", :locals => { :variable_name => variable} %>
```

You can change it to your own data. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use partials:

In index.html.erb

```
<h1>New zone</h1>
<%= render partial: "lightbox", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

Inside same directory you should user a file '_lightbox.html.erb'
Inside this file you can render another partial:

```
<h2>Inside new zone</h2>
<%= render partial: "lightbox2", locals: {var: zone} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

since rails4 you can omit `partial` and `locals`

```
<%= render 'path/to/partial/file2', var2: var1 %>
```